# Why compiler always choose non explicit constructor for copy-list-initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, copy-constructor

For below code, is there any reason compiler will choose non-explicit constructor..

```
struct S {
    S() = default;
    explicit S(S & cp) {
      std::cout << "explicit" << std::endl;
    } 
    S(const S & cp) {
      std::cout << "copy" << std::endl;
    };
};


int main() {  
    S s1; 
    S s2 = {s1}; 
}
```

from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization, it says for copy-list-ini... both explicit and non-explicit constructors are considered, but only non-explicit constructors may be called

https://godbolt.org/z/YqWWs9jqY

Comment: It is *extremely* unusual for a class to have two copy constructors. It is even *more* unusual for a copy constructor to be `explicit`. If you are a beginner, just don't go down this rabbit hole! It never happens in real code.

Comment: This is in real code, and was confused why compiler was choosing copy instead of explicit.

Comment: The explicit constructor should be chosen, with the result that the program is ill-formed, particularly as of [CWG 2137](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2137). However Clang is yet to implement CWG 2137, and GCC may have missed taking into account the effects on explicit constructors due to the wording changes.

Answer (score 7):

#### The program is ill-formed, but there exists implementation divergence

As of [CWG 2137](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2137) your program should be ill-formed. However there is implementation divergence here, where Clang is yet to implement CWG 2137 and where GCC have implemented most parts of CWG 2137, however potentially missing the case for explicit constructors in the context copy-list-initialization (with a single element of the same class).

Bug reports (I just posted the GCC one):

- Clang: [Single-element initializer_list invokes wrong constructor #24186](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/24186)
- GCC: [Bug 110958 - [CWG 2137][accepts-invalid] Copy-list-initialization with single element of same class only considers converting constructors as viable](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=110958)

#### The rules

[[dcl.init.list]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list) governs the rules for list-initialization, and for the following:

> ```
> S s2 = {s1};
> ```

as of CWG 2137, [[dcl.init.list]/3.7](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#3.7) applies:

> Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution ([over.match], [over.match.list]). If a narrowing conversion (see below) is required to convert any of the arguments, the program is ill-formed.

As there are no initializer list constructors, [[over.match.list]/1.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list#1.2) applies:

> /1.2 Otherwise, or if no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.
>
> In copy-list-initialization, if an explicit constructor is chosen, the initialization is ill-formed.

As the explicit constructor is a better match it should be selected after which the program is ill-formed, as [over.match.list]/1 does not allow explicit constructor in copy-list-initialization.

Both GCC and Clang are wrong to accept the program, but Clang due to not yet implementing CWG 2137, and GCC a bit less so due to missing somewhat of an edge case introduced by CWG 2137.